# Minecraft Forge 1.7.10 Startup Error

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge

My Minecraft has a lot of mods in it. While testing to see if they are compatible I recieved this error on startup:

"Forge Mod Loader has found a problem with your installation. The mods and versions listed below could not be found: Forge: minimum version required is 10.13.3."

So Forge can't find itself? Running MC 1.7.10 and Forge 10.13.2.1291

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about tech support for modded Minecraft.  We only support vanilla Minecraft for crashes and troubleshooting.

Comment: Just an explanation of this error though: YOu have a mod that requires a minimum version of forge that is 10.13.3, you are running forge 10.13.2. So it is saying that you need to upgrade forge for one of the mods you have installed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is tech support for modded Minecraft. We only provide tech support for vanilla Minecraft

Answer (score 2):

Update your forge, you have answered the question yourself :)

Comment: Forge: minimum version required is 10.13.3. as stated in the question you are using "Forge 10.13.2.1291"  Forge, **10.13.2.**1291